# Is there a way to show month and year in dropdown in bootstrap ui datepicker

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

We are using [bootstrap ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) in our angularjs project. Is there a way to display years and month in drop-down in datepicker popup.

Comment: > datepickerMode (Default: day) - Current mode of the datepicker (day|month|year). Can be used to initialize the datepicker in a specific mode.

Comment: datepickerMode will display only one mode at a time like day, month or year. I am looking for day mode with month and year in dropdown in place of title button

Comment: @PraveenKumarP did you eve figure this out?